# Classify own extension methods

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I would like to know if it is possible to "classify" my extension methods.

I created extensions that are coming from SQL world (LEFT / RIGHT / COALESCE / (NOT) IN / (NOT) BETWEEN / ...) and would like to extend it in submethod "SQL" and use it like this :

```
"abc".SQL().Left(2);
```

or should I create a static class that reference this methods?

Thanks for any advice and tell me the best practice in this case.

Comment: So you want nested extension methods? That really misses the whole point of an extension method...

Comment: You can't extend a method, you can only extend a type (return type of the method). If `SQL()` returns your own custom type, why not just add those methods to the type directly?

Comment: @Chris : Just to know that these methods are using the SQL rules... But it's maybe a bad practice ;)

Comment: I don't completely understand your problem. It appears that `SQL` is an extension method of `String`? Now you want to extend the type that `SQL` returns to add `Left(Integer)` what is the return type of the `SQL` extension method? That is where your new methods should go, if you can't modify that type then you need to extend it in the same way you did `String`.

Comment: @Chris : See Kristoffers answer. I would like to do a fluent interface, but you're right, it's the SQL that should be extended ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what people call a [fluent interface](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html). **It's really only the SQL() method that needs to be an extension method** (on the string class). The SQL method can then **return a class that has the methods** like Left() and Coalesce(). If you want to make that extendable, you can extend the class/interface that you SQL method returns.

The methods (Left, Coalesce, etc) can all return the same class/interface, to get the flow of a fluent interface, such as

```
string b = "abc".SQL().Left(2).Right(1).ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create the `SQL()` as an entension method that returns a class that contains your extensions (as normal methods) that return this new class. The class would have to have a property/field that was your orignal object that called the `SQL()` method.

EDIT: Thanks to @Kristoffer i now know this is called a `fluent interface`; where the API is designed to allow for more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can achieve this. The code needs some tweaking, but just to get you started:

First, create a 'builder'-type class that manipulates a string using your Sql methods

```
 class SqlMethods
 {
      string _target; // probably want to use a StringBuilder instead

      public SqlMethods(string target)
      {
          _target = target;
      }

      SqlMethods Left(int n)
      {
          _target = ...; // implementation of Left()
          return this;
      } 

      public override string ToString() {return _target;}
 }
```

Instantiate this class through an extension method, like this:

```
static class StringExtensions
{
     public static SqlMethods SQL(this string s) {return new SqlMethods(s);}
}
```

This allows for an API like this:

```
"abc".SQL().Left(2).ToString()
```